# PostgreSQL: LEFT JOIN creates blank row

Tags: postgresql, null, left-join, duplicates, sql-insert

**See important new discoveries 1 and 2 at end of this explanation.**

I am running Postgres 9.1.3 and am having a weird left join issue.

I have a table named **consistent.master** with over 2 million rows. It has a column named **citation_id**, and that column has no nulls. I can verify that with this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM consistent.master
WHERE citation_id IS NULL
```

That returns **0**.

Here's where it gets weird: if I **LEFT JOIN** this table to a temporary table, I get an error that I am trying to insert a null into the **citation_id** field:

**ERROR: null value in column "citation_id" violates not-null constraint
SQL state: 23502**

Here's the query:

```
WITH stops AS (
    SELECT citation_id,
           rank() OVER (ORDER BY offense_timestamp,
                     defendant_dl,
                     offense_street_number,
                     offense_street_name) AS stop
    FROM   consistent.master
    WHERE  citing_jurisdiction=1
)

INSERT INTO consistent.masternew (arrest_id, citation_id, defendant_dl, defendant_dl_state, defendant_zip, defendant_race, defendant_sex, defendant_dob, vehicle_licenseplate, vehicle_licenseplate_state, vehicle_registration_expiration_date, vehicle_year, vehicle_make, vehicle_model, vehicle_color, offense_timestamp, offense_street_number, offense_street_name, offense_crossstreet_number, offense_crossstreet_name, offense_county, officer_id, offense_code, speed_alleged, speed_limit, work_zone, school_zone, offense_location, id, source, citing_jurisdiction, the_geom)

SELECT stops.stop, master.citation_id, defendant_dl, defendant_dl_state, defendant_zip, defendant_race, defendant_sex, defendant_dob, vehicle_licenseplate, vehicle_licenseplate_state, vehicle_registration_expiration_date, vehicle_year, vehicle_make, vehicle_model, vehicle_color, offense_timestamp, offense_street_number, offense_street_name, offense_crossstreet_number, offense_crossstreet_name, offense_county, officer_id, offense_code, speed_alleged, speed_limit, work_zone, school_zone, offense_location, id, source, citing_jurisdiction, the_geom
FROM consistent.master LEFT JOIN stops
ON stops.citation_id = master.citation_id
```

I'm scratching my head on this one. If this is a **LEFT JOIN**, and if **consistent.master** is the join's left table, how could this query create null values in the **citation_id** column when there aren't any to begin with?

Here's the SQL code I used to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE consistent.masternew
(
  arrest_id character varying(20),
  citation_id character varying(20) NOT NULL,
  defendant_dl character varying(20),
  defendant_dl_state character varying(2),
  defendant_zip character varying(9),
  defendant_race character varying(10),
  defendant_sex character(1),
  defendant_dob date,
  vehicle_licenseplate character varying(10),
  vehicle_licenseplate_state character(2),
  vehicle_registration_expiration_date date,
  vehicle_year integer,
  vehicle_make character varying(20),
  vehicle_model character varying(20),
  vehicle_color character varying,
  offense_timestamp timestamp without time zone,
  offense_street_number character varying(10),
  offense_street_name character varying(30),
  offense_crossstreet_number character varying(10),
  offense_crossstreet_name character varying(30),
  offense_county character varying(10),
  officer_id character varying(20),
  offense_code integer,
  speed_alleged integer,
  speed_limit integer,
  work_zone bit(1),
  school_zone bit(1),
  offense_location point,
  id serial NOT NULL,
  source character varying(20), -- Where this citation came from--court, PD, etc.
  citing_jurisdiction integer,
  the_geom geometry,
  CONSTRAINT masternew_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id ),
  CONSTRAINT citing_jurisdiction FOREIGN KEY (citing_jurisdiction)
      REFERENCES consistent.jurisdictions (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT offenses FOREIGN KEY (offense_code)
      REFERENCES consistent.offenses (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT enforce_dims_the_geom CHECK (st_ndims(the_geom) = 2),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_geotype_the_geom CHECK (geometrytype(the_geom) = 'POINT'::text OR the_geom IS NULL),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_srid_the_geom CHECK (st_srid(the_geom) = 3081)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE consistent.masternew
  OWNER TO postgres;
COMMENT ON COLUMN consistent.masternew.source IS 'Where this citation came from--court, PD, etc.';

CREATE INDEX masternew_citation_id_idx
  ON consistent.masternew
  USING btree
  (citation_id COLLATE pg_catalog."default" );

CREATE INDEX masternew_citing_jurisdiction_idx
  ON consistent.masternew
  USING btree
  (citing_jurisdiction );

CREATE INDEX masternew_defendant_dl_idx
  ON consistent.masternew
  USING btree
  (defendant_dl COLLATE pg_catalog."default" );

CREATE INDEX masternew_id_idx
  ON consistent.masternew
  USING btree
  (id );

CREATE INDEX masternew_offense_street_name_idx
  ON consistent.masternew
  USING btree
  (offense_street_name COLLATE pg_catalog."default" );

CREATE INDEX masternew_offense_street_number_idx
  ON consistent.masternew
  USING btree
  (offense_street_number COLLATE pg_catalog."default" );

CREATE INDEX masternew_offense_timestamp_idx
  ON consistent.masternew
  USING btree
  (offense_timestamp );

CREATE INDEX masternew_the_geom_idx
  ON consistent.masternew
  USING gist
  (the_geom );
```

**IMPORTANT DISCOVERY 1**

I just discovered something interesting. This query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM consistent.master
WHERE citation_id IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM consistent.master
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM consistent.master
WHERE citation_id IS NULL
```

The results are:

```
2085344
2085343
0
```

How can I possibly explain that? How can the count with `WHERE citation_id IS NOT NULL` possibly be higher than the same query with no `WHERE` clause?

**IMPORTANT DISCOVERY 2**
OK, per the comments below, I discovered that I have a row with all empty values, and this is *despite* the fact that the table has a serial `id` column and some `NOT NULL` constraints.

I deleted the bum row. Now I'm not getting the null error. Instead, I'm getting this:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "masternew_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1583804) already exists.

********** Error **********

ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "masternew_pkey"
SQL state: 23505
Detail: Key (id)=(1583804) already exists.
```

So just to make sure, I do this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM consistent.master
WHERE id=1583804;
```

Guess what? `consistent.master` only has 1 instance of this! So given that the left table in the `LEFT JOIN` only 1 instance of **1583804** in `citation_id` **and** that the **id** column can only come from the left table, how could this error possibly happen? A `LEFT JOIN` like this should not cause the final result to have more rows than the left table, right?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you say `consistent.master.citation_id` in the SELECT part, no just `master.citation_id` (like you do everywhere else)?

Comment: I didn't look at this too much, but if you explicitly label the fields in the insert, will it still do this? `INSERT INTO consistent.masternew(stop,citation_id,defendant_dl,citing_jurisdiction,geometry)`

Comment: Also usually the `WITH` statement comes first (prior to the `INSERT INTO...`)

Comment: @Thilo: Thanks. Changed that, but it didn't fix anything.

Comment: @vol7ron: Thanks. I changed to label the fields (see revised question above), and I moved the **WITH** to be before the **INSERT INTO**. Neither had any effect.

Comment: @ArenCambre: This is peculiar - assuming you have now labeled the field pairs.  My initial thought is that table `stops` doesn't exist, isn't populated, or exists in another schema; but you are defining it with the `WITH`.  I would start by running just the `with/select` portion of your query to see if any results are returned.  If results are returned, throw in a `WHERE citation_id IS NULL` and see if any records are returned. -- is it possible you don't have any citings in jurisdiction 1?

Comment: @vol7ron: Suppose you're right and `stops` has no data. Does it matter? I am not pulling `citation_id` from it.

Comment: @ArenCambre: that's a good question.  I would think not, but I'm curious if no records are returned, whether or not it would have a row of NULLs.  My guess is not, but there has to be something going on here - I have never seen something like this in Postgres.  If you can't find an answer here, I'd recommend getting on IRC and going to the #postgresql channel for guys that really know their stuff.

Comment: @vol7ron: I ran the `SELECT` in the `WITH` by itself, and I get 2,057,974 rows, as I expected, after several seconds. I then ran it with `WHERE citation_id IS NULL` and immediately (in 65 ms) got 0 results. I think it was immediate because that column has an index.

Comment: @ArenCambre: I don't have much more in my pocket.  I'd try giving the master table an alias and using the alias instead of `master` incase there is a conflict with the schema.tablename syntax

Comment: also, I don't think you have to use the table name if you do `USING(citation_id)` instead of your `ON stops.citation_id = master.citation_id`

Comment: haha - I just noticed my last two comments was what Erwin was saying - I had only read his `With` information.  If you tried his last example, i'd seek help from the Postgres contributors

Comment: Thanks. I changed the very end of the query to `FROM consistent.master LEFT JOIN stops USING (citation_id)`, and it had no effect.

Comment: Just discovered something really interesting: a `SELECT COUNT(*)` with a `WHERE` clause returns a larger number than without the `WHERE`. See the end of my question above.

Comment: OK, I found there was a row with all blanks, even though the table definition prohibits this. I deleted that row. Now the query returns a different error that seems to be impossible given the database and the query. I've documented it at the end of my question.

Comment: Deleting the row with blanks, and not inserting into the `id` serial column appears to have fixed everything. I marked @ErwinBrandstetter's answer as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With an INSERT, especially with a complex one, you should **always define the target columns**. So make that:

```
INSERT INTO consistent.masternew (citation_id, col1, col2, ...)
```

If anything goes wrong in the accompanying SELECT statement - like this:

```
the_geom geometry
```

(makes no sense to rename the column with a type name - I assume this is unintended) - or if the underlying table definition changes, an INSERT statement without defined target columns can go terribly wrong.

PostgreSQL does not enforce the same number of columns in the SELECT statement as are in the target table. I quote [the fine manual on that](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-insert.html):

> Each column not present in the explicit or implicit column list will
>   be filled with a default value, either its declared default value **or
>   null if there is none**.

(Bold emphasis mine.) If you have a mismatch in the column list, this could make a NULL value appear "out of nowhere".

Also, the **order of the columns** in the SELECT statement has to match the order of the columns to insert into. If the target columns are not spelled out, this would be the order of the columns in your table as it was created.
You seem to expect that columns are matched by name automatically, but that is not so. Column names in the SELECT statement are completely irrelevant for the final step of the INSERT. Only their order from left to right is significant.

Contrary to what others have implied the **WITH clause is perfectly legit**. I quote [the manual on INSERT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-insert.html#AEN72782):

> It is possible for the query (SELECT statement) to also contain a WITH
>   clause. In such a case both sets of with_query can be referenced
>   within the query, but the second one takes precedence since it is more
>   closely nested.

Your statement could look like this:

```
WITH stops AS (
    SELECT citation_id
          ,rank() OVER (ORDER BY
                    offense_timestamp
                   ,defendant_dl
                   ,offense_street_number
                   ,offense_street_name) AS stop
    FROM   consistent.master
    WHERE  citing_jurisdiction = 1
    )
INSERT INTO consistent.masternew (citation_id, col1, col2, ...) -- add columns
SELECT m.citation_id -- order colums accordingly!
      ,s.stop
      ,m.defendant_dl
        -- 27 more columns
      ,m.citing_jurisdiction
      ,m.the_geom
FROM   consistent.master m
LEFT   JOIN stops s USING (citation_id);
```

Comment: Thanks. Good catch on **the_geom geometry**. That was because I took my original **CREATE TABLE** query and used it to build the **SELECT**. I added the explicit target column names after the **INSERT INTO**, and I am running into the same problem still, a null value in the **citation_id** field. I'll modify the problem statement up top with the new query.

Comment: Interesting find on the `WITH`

Comment: +1 - I didn't read your whole answer and said the same thing in my comments, then read your answer and turns out you listed everything I suggested.  I'd give multiple pluses if I could (for correcting me on the `WITH` info)

Comment: @ArenCambre; If you tried my syntax and it still does not work, then there is few explanations left. Do you have `rules` or `triggers` in place for `consistent.masternew`? If not, then there is probably something wrong with your database. If you can try a complete dump / restore to a new database cluster and see if the problem is still there ..? You might try to use a subquery instead of the WITH clause, just to rule out a problem with the CTE implementation.

Comment: Thanks. No rules or triggers. I've updated the original question to show the query I used to make the `masternew` table. It wouldn't surprise me at all if I'm running into some bug here. I previously did a similar `LEFT JOIN` and found that it was duplicating a few hundred rows, causing my total row count to swell a bit from the left table's original count.

Comment: @ArenCambre: Are you sure you did not just have multiple matches to the right hand table? I have been working with PostgreSQL since version 7.1 and have never once seen a bug resulting from a join operation. When something was off, it always turned out to be me.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: How would multiple matches cause a null in `citation_id`? Seems like the worst that would cause is two rows with the same `citation_id`, and that is not a problem under my current schema. Maybe that could cause a duplicate key error in the `id` column, but that's not the error I'm getting.

Comment: @Aren: I was referring to your previous comment, not to NULLs.

Comment: I see your point, but for that to happen, the `SELECT` in the `WITH` clause would have to cause duplicated rows. Not clear how that could happen.

Comment: Just discovered something really interesting: a `SELECT COUNT(*)` with a `WHERE` clause returns a larger number than without the `WHERE`. See the end of my question above.

Comment: That result is a definite sign of breakage. Try to copy the whole table to a new table or a [`CLUSTER`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-cluster.html) the existing table with some index (also rewrites the table) and see if that fixes the count. If not, I would try a complete dump / restore.

Comment: Found that there's a blank row at row 583847. When I do a CSV export, all I see are commas for that row.

Comment: @ArenCambre: So that clears it up? I was assuming you had a not null constraint / primary key to rule that out.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: I did. That's what I don't understand. The entire row was blank.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9009/discussion-between-aren-cambre-and-erwin-brandstetter)

Comment: OK, removing the null *and also* removing the `id` field fixed everything. I've accepted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

At a guess I'd say that you are inserting stops.stop, which could be null, into the citation_id column, but without knowing the table structure I can't say for sure :)

EDIT:  Try @vol7ron's suggestion and name the columns...

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. The table structure exactly matches the order of the columns in the SELECT query. In fact, I built that list based on the table's **CREATE TABLE** query.

Comment: BTW, I added explicit column names to the **INSERT INTO** and still have the same problem.