# Insert script to auto populate numbers 1-1000?

Tags: postgresql, scripting, pgadmin

I have a single table with a single column called id as shown below. I need to populate the table with numbers 1-1000, how can I do that with the scripting?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use [generate_series](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) to this:

```
--Without column declaration
INSERT INTO "MyTable" SELECT generate_series(1, 1000);

--With column declaration
INSERT INTO "MyTable"(id) SELECT generate_series(1, 1000);
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks that works. Just for my own future knowledge, why did you not have to specify the column it is to be populated under? For example, the image that I posted has "id" as the column.

Comment: You can ommit column declaration when *inserted values* has same number of columns of your table.

Comment: BTW, good new article about `generate_series()`: https://regilero.github.io/postgresql/english/2017/06/26/postgresql_advanced_generate_series/

Comment: Very good article indeed. Thanks @Nick

Comment: @michel.milezzi: Actually, you *can* omit target column names even with fewer values than columns in the table. Columns are filled in declared order. Details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11885152/939860 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/9714052/939860. Only advisable for ad hoc use. It would be a trap in persisted statements. Table definitions can change ...

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Well, I did not ever realized that. Thanks.